# Loading XDocument while validating against schema in .NET 3.5

Tags: .net

Input is xml as a string and I have a XSD schema to verify against.

I wish to validate the xml against the XSD schema while loading the xml into an XDocument (requirement since I need to do parsing with Linq afterwards).

Anyone has a small code-snippet?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Load the document, and then use [`XDocument.Validate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.validate.aspx), passing in an `XmlSchemaSet` to represent the schemas you want to validate against, and a `ValidationEventHandler` to react appropriately to any validation problems.

There's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx) with a complete example and discussion.

Answer (score 15):

Just a note about the above answer.  It is correct but can be confusing. XDocument.Validate is an extension method that exists in the System.Xml.Schema namespace.  If you do not use this namespace then the Validate method will not appear in intellisense.  Just thought I'd help those who were as confused as I was. :)

Answer (score 2):

So the code is here.

From Jon Skeets answer and MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.validate.aspx

```
var xsdMarkup =
    @"<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
<xsd:element name='Root'>
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name='Child1' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='1'/>
    <xsd:element name='Child2' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='1'/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>";
var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup)));

var doc1 = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Root",
                    new XElement("Child1", "content1"),
                    new XElement("Child2", "content1")
        )
    );

var doc2 = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Root",
                    new XElement("Child1", "content1"),
                    new XElement("Child3", "content1")
        )
    );

Console.WriteLine("Validating doc1");
var errors = false;
doc1.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
                                errors = true;
                            });
Console.WriteLine("doc1 {0}", errors ? "did not validate" : "validated");

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Validating doc2");
errors = false;
doc2.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
                                errors = true;
                            });
Console.WriteLine("doc2 {0}", errors ? "did not validate" : "validated");
```

Comment: I have XSD file, using `var stream = new StreamReader(pathXSD)` ***not working***